# A group with an element of finite order and another element of infinite order?

Tags: group-theory, order-theory

I have a (probably) stupid question. I'm in an intro to group theory class and I am trying to better grasp the concept of element order. My question is if I have a group and it has an element of order 3 (or anything finite), can this group also have an element of infinite order? This isn't a homework problem, just trying to grasp basic concepts. I know elements of say a cyclic group have finite order and I know in an infinite group 'I' has order 1, but what about non trivial element orders? I feel stupid for asking this in such a public forum, but I'm also quite curious. No hurry and thank you for your input.

Comment: The direct product $\Bbb{Z} \times C_2$ has both elements of finite and infinite order.

Comment: Oh yes! I see that! Thank you so much, that example does make sense. I'm going to play around with it. Thank you for your time.